# how does tomcat know where to search my intellij projects?

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, catalina

I have tomcat 8 installed on my ubuntu local machine. Also, I'm using Intellij IDEA 14. I have configured tomcat and IDEA so that they work together well. But, tomcat really needs to search projects on my local machine when its started. for example :

*/home/rezo/.IntelliJIdea14/system/tomcat/Unnamed_WebOnlineGame_12*

this is where IDEA saves the project when it is deployed

my question is : where is this path specified as CATALINA_BASE ?